# run job on server using ssh key

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy on this server **serverBNP-prod1**
I tried to write this code below. Using this code where should i add my ssh local key please?

Thank you

```
job_deploy_prod:
stage: deploy
only:
 - master
 - tags
when: manual
environment:
name: prod
variables:
SERVER: serverBNP-prod1
SSH_OPTS: -p 22 -l udoc -o BatchMode=true -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
script:
- export VERSION=$(fgrep -m 1 -w version pom.xml | sed -re 's/^.*>(.*)<.*$/\1/')
- ssh $SSH_OPTS -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa $SERVER "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com"
- ssh $SSH_OPTS -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa $SERVER "docker rm -f proj"
- ssh $SSH_OPTS -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa $SERVER "docker pull registry.gitlab.com/bnp/proj:$VERSION"
- ssh $SSH_OPTS -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa $SERVER "docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e 'SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod' -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone --name proj registry.gitlab.com/bnp/proj:$VERSION"
```

tags:
- prod

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- use a `Settings` / `CI-CD` / `Variable` of type `File`, in which you will put your private key data, or
- if you have only a username and password for your server you can use the ''sshpass'' command and provide a `SSHPASS` environment variable, still in the CI-CD variables section

More details on how to use the GitLab CI/CD environment variables (File type, security, etc.) can be found here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/

You can *mask* variables but be aware that contrary to Jenkins there is no way to remove the "Reveal value" button when a user has sufficient rights in Gitlab to view/edit the settings, so you will have to carefully select your project rights, e.g., by allowing other people the *Developer* right but without the *Maintainer* one (which allows to edit the settings).